# Communication between Node.js socket and external tcp socket via ZMQ

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, zeromq

I'm trying communicate between a Node.js socket (I am using [zmq](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node)) and an external tcp socket via [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/).

The external socket (`tcp://***.***.***.***:5555`) is a part of a C++ service, and he acts like a `dealer`.

The Node.js server should act like a `router`, which should monitor and pass messages to the available `workers` (that should be received from the external tcp socket).

The connection is successfully made between both services, but once I am connected to the tcp socket, I don't receive any `message` from the external service.

```
# Node.js server

let zmq = require('zmq');
socket = zmq.socket('router');

// Successfully connected
socket.on('connect', () => {console.log('Connected!')}); 

// No message received from tcp
socket.on('message', (message) => {console.log('Message: ', message)}); 

socket.monitor(500, 0);
socket.connect('tcp://***.***.***.***:5555');
```

Any thought will be very welcomed!

Comment: How do you know that the remote **`ZMQ_DEALER`** AccessPoint-archetype node actually does send any messages to your side?

Comment: ```ZMQ_DEALER``` successfully interacts with a Python socket, which receives multipart messages (via ```socket.recv_multipart()```) once he is bound to the ```ZMQ_DEALER```'s PORT. If so, the Node.js socket shouldn't receive multipart messages (via ```socket.on('message', ...)```) once he is connected to the ```ZMQ_DEALER``` tcp?

Comment: Sorry, did not get your point. So, given a **`ZMQ_DEALER`** has already made **`.bind( "tcp://<AddrA>:<port#A>" )`**, next, some python node, having an appropriate AccessPoint-type ( matching a legally-correct distributed Scalable Formal Communication Archetype Pattern ), then can try to `.connect( "tcp://<AddrA>:<port#A>" )`. Do you say, that given python succeeded in doing so, indeed `.recv()`-s messages, but your Node.js `socket.connect( "tcp://<Addr>:<port#>" );` throws `socket.on('connect', ...)` event, but never a `socket.on('message', .. )`?

Comment: @user3666197 you are almost right.. ```ZMQ_DEALER``` connects to the tcp address, and the Python router binds to the ```tcp://*:<port#A>```, while they run on the same server. And yes, the Node.js socket (which is not running on the same server with the ```ZMQ_DEALER```) successfully connects to this tcp address, but it doesn't receive messages.